# urand in Oracle Database

Tags: c++, database, oracle, plsql, uniform-distribution

I'm using Oracle Database 12c. Is there a way to generate uniformly distributed floating point numbers like we have in C++ (urand() )?

Or any subroutine which could do so. DBMS_RANDOM package has functionality for Normal Distribution but not uniform distribution

Comment: Isn't that just `dbms_random.value`?

Answer (score 2):

`DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` generates values in a uniform distribution.

Although [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_random.htm#ARPLS040) does not explicitly state how `VALUE` randomize numbers I think we can be confident it uses a uniform distribution because:

1. That's the easiest way to do it, and there's already another function that provides a normalized distribution.
2. The quick test case below verifies the numbers look to be uniformly distributed.

For the test, set a seed so that everyone's results will match:

```
begin
    dbms_random.seed(val => 'abcd');
end;
/
```

For the test code, generate 100,000 random values, count them, and put them in buckets with rounding:

```
--Compare DBMS_RANDOM.NORMAL and DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE.
select normal_value, normal_count, value_count
from
(
    --NORMAL
    select round(random_value, 1) normal_value, count(*) normal_count
    from
    (
        select
            dbms_random.normal random_value
        from dual
        connect by level <= 100000
    )
    group by round(random_value, 1)
    order by normal_value
) normal_values
join
(
    --VALUE
    select round(random_value, 1) value_value, count(*) value_count
    from
    (
        select
            dbms_random.value(-3,3) random_value
        from dual
        connect by level <= 100000
    )
    group by round(random_value, 1)
    order by value_value
) value_values
on normal_values.normal_value = value_values.value_value
order by 1;
```

Export the values to LibreOffice and then you too can generate this ugly chart:

[image]